# Julia-lang constructor with partial default value

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and it's an exciting language. I just come across some weird behavior that I cannot find an explanation online. I appreciate your help.

```
    versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.4.0

Commit 0ff703b* (2015-10-08 06:20 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

I defined a structure

```
type mytype
    x :: UInt8
    y :: UInt8
    mytype(n::UInt8) = new(n, 0)
end
```

The type contains a constructor that has a default value for one field and takes input for the other. Then I test it

```
 mytype(1)

LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{mytype}, ::Int64)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor mytype(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)
  mytype(!Matched::UInt8)
while loading In[56], in expression starting on line 1

 in call at essentials.jl:56
```

The error message is very confusing and I can't understand it. I tested that if I provide default values to the two parameters or take the two inputs, the code works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I get

```
julia> mytype(1)
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{mytype}, ::Int64)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor mytype(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, ::T)
  mytype(::UInt8)
 in call at essentials.jl:56
```

To break it down, it says it tried to call the constructor, but no constructor matched. Why did no constructor match? Because there is no automatic conversion defined from `Int64` (the `1`) to `UInt8`.

It then tried `convert`ing a `Int64` into `mytype`, but that method isn't defined either. It then gave up, and displayed the closest things to the thing it originally tried (`mytype(::Int64)`).

You might want to provide additional methods to handle this, or accept any integer in your constructor and use `convert` to force it to `UInt8` - if it fails, it'll throw an exception:

```
julia> type mynewtype
           x :: UInt8
           y :: UInt8
           mynewtype(n::Integer) = new(n, 0)
       end

julia> mynewtype(5)
mynewtype(0x05,0x00)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original question,`mytype` 's member `y` will always be 0 because the type inner constructor is called with the second argument 0.
They way to construct an instance in this case is : `mytype(UInt8(25))` which yields `mytype2(0x19,0x00)`.
However, it cannot accept values for `y`: `mytype(UInt8(5), UInt8(23))` yields an error.

In the answer, `mynewtype` can handle normal Int64 through the inner constructor however, it will always initialize the `y` with 0 as well ... 
In Julia, the inner constructor initializes the members of the type.The way to properly handle different argument signatures is by defining the type:

    `type mytype2
         x::UInt8
         y::UInt8
       end`

and an outer constructor: `mytype2(n::Integer) = mytype2(n,0)` which calls the default, implicit (and invisible), inner constructor `mytype2(x,y) = new(x,y)`.

mytype2 can be verified by `mytype2(1,2)` which yields `mytype2(0x01,0x02)` and, `mytype2(1)` which yields `mytype2(0x01,0x00)`.

More info at : [Julia 0.4 constructors documentation page](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/constructors/), "Inner Constructor Methods" (recommendations for safe type definitions at the end of the section)